# How to install Adium theme for Pidgin?

Tags: 10.10, pidgin

I searched Google and realized that they only made tutorial *(install Adium theme for Pidgin)* in Ubuntu 9.10 or 10.4. I try their tutorial in my Maverick but unsuccessful.

I see that in menu Tool>Plugin of Pidgin I cannot find item WebKit Message Styles to check/uncheck.

Anyone has succeeded in installing Adium theme for Pidgin in Maverick, tell me the way to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Officially Pidgin does not support adium themes, and to my knowledge, the plugin has not been updated (or available) for a rather long time. I'd like to be proven wrong, but I don't think you will be able to use this feature.

Comment: Thx for quickly answer. I applied Adium theme for Empathy, I realized that it's nice and cute. But Pidgin has more functions than Emapthy, so I'd like to use Adium theme for Pidgin. Sadly for the news that the author has not still developed Adium theme for Pidgin. Wish a good news next time...

Answer (score 2):

I found a script that works fine in Ubuntu Natty, Oneiric and Precise may be works with Maverick:

```
#!/bin/bash 

HOMEUSER=$(echo ~ | awk -F'/' '{ print $1 $2 $3 }' | sed 's/home//g') 
SCRIPTSDIR="/home/$HOMEUSER/.scripts" 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webkit-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes pidgin libnotify-bin pidgin-dev libpurple-dev libwebkit-dev bzr checkinstall 
bzr branch lp:~pdffs/pidgin-webkit/karmic-fixes 
cd ./karmic-fixes/ 
make 
sudo checkinstall --fstrans=no --install=yes --pkgname=pidgin-adium --pkgversion "0.1" --default 
cd .. 
sudo rm -r ./karmic-fixes/ 
mkdir -p /home/$HOMEUSER/.scripts/ 
sleep 2; 
cd $SCRIPTSDIR/ 
sleep 2; 
wget http://webupd8.googlecode.com/files/pidgin_adium.sh; 
chmod +x $SCRIPTSDIR/pidgin_adium.sh; 
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/adiumxtra/command "$SCRIPTSDIR/pidgin-adium.sh %s" 
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/adiumxtra/enabled true 
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/adiumxtra/needs_terminal false 
sudo chown $HOMEUSER -R /home/$HOMEUSER/.purple/ 
cd /home/$HOMEUSER/.purple/message_styles 
wget http://www.adiumxtras.com/download/2160 
unzip /home/$HOMEUSER/.purple/message_styles/2160 
sudo rm /home/$HOMEUSER/.purple/message_styles/2160
```

Open gedit, copy the code and save the file in your home folder. 
Set it as executable: `Right click on file > permissions > check Allow executing file as program` Then double click on the file, execute in a terminal, write your password and the script will install the dependencies and the `WebKit messages styles` plugin for pidgin.

Answer (score 1):

THIS WORKS EVEN IN QUANTAL (UBUNTU 12.10) 32 & 64 BIT!!!

Never mind the name "karmic-fixes", just create a a new file in your home folder, copy and paste the text below, save the file, make it executable, and run it in terminal.

It will install **pidgin**, if not installed already, and then all the necessary files etc. to start using pidgin with a rich set of **adium styles** which can selected from the menu:

**Tools > Plugins > WebKit message styles > Configure plugin...** and then select from a list of adium styles.

*Note: I've written the script below simply by blending [edocastillo](https://askubuntu.com/users/25928/edocastillo)'s script above and [h!v](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=455603)'s script here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1315515.*

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes pidgin libnotify-bin pidgin-dev libpurple-dev libwebkit-dev bzr wget checkinstall 
mkdir $HOME/.bin
cd "$HOME/.bin/"
wget --no-verbose -O adium-pidgin "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/422036/adium-pidgin"
chmod +x adium-pidgin
cd "$HOME"
TMPDIR=`mktemp -d`
cd $TMPDIR
bzr branch lp:~pdffs/pidgin-webkit/karmic-fixes
cd karmic-fixes
make
mkdir -p "$HOME/.purple/plugins"
cp webkit.so "$HOME/.purple/plugins/webkit.so"
rm -rf $TMPDIR
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/adiumxtra/command "$HOME/.bin/adium-pidgin %s"
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/adiumxtra/enabled true
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/adiumxtra/needs_terminal false
mkdir -p "$HOME/.purple/message_styles"
cd $HOME/.purple/message_styles 
wget http://www.adiumxtras.com/download/2160 
unzip $HOME/.purple/message_styles/2160 
rm -f $HOME/.purple/message_styles/2160
exit 0
```

**UPDATE:** If the bzr branch is no longer valid, you can alternatively download the folder "karmic-fixes" from here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7EHkKCNZtpuMWVtUE5hb0pUbkU

Comment: The bzr branch doesn't exists any more. Can you re-upload? Thanks.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Added an update at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get notification for this eply. Can you please reupload one more time? I am trying to revive this for pidgin 3. Thanks.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam I'm sorry that you missed that. Unfortunately I can't find any item named "karmic" in my computer any longer - probably dumped in one of the deep cleaning operations in the past 7 years.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The drive link you shared is lno longer valid. Thats is why I amasking. Do you know any other source that I can get it from ? Perhaps I should post a topic on Ubuntu forums if someone still have it ?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam I probably uploaded to Google Drive from my computer, but unfortunately it doesn't exist here or there anymore. You might try your luck elsewhere.