# How do I install Adium themes in Pidgin?

Tags: 11.10, pidgin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Adium theme for Pidgin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45343/how-to-install-adium-theme-for-pidgin)

Any chance to install adium themes in pidgin on Ubuntu 11.10? I try tutorials for 9.10 and 10.10 but unsuccessful.

## Update 25 Nov 2011

I think this question can not be considered duplicate, since it refers to the version 11.10.

How to install on Ubuntu 11.10 (based on Karmic installation with some changes):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webkit-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes pidgin-dev libpurple-dev libwebkit-dev bzr checkinstall
bzr branch lp:~pdffs/pidgin-webkit/karmic-fixes
cd karmic-fixes/
make
sudo checkinstall --fstrans=no --install=yes --pkgname=pidgin-adium --pkgversion "0.1" --default
cd ..
sudo rm -r karmic-fixes/
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.purple/
```

That's it!

Comment: Pidgin does not support adium themes in 11.10, because the plugin is no longer developed.